# Expected to return a value in arrow; function array-callback-return. Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I'm having some issues understanding why I'm getting a compile warning on this piece of my react code

```
fetch('/users')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            data.map(users => {
                console.log(users);
            });
        });
```

The warning I'm getting is `Expected to return a value in arrow function  array-callback-return`

However I'm still get the json object values from my `/users`, and they are printed to the console individually. The object is:

```
    {
        id: 1,
        username: "Foo"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        username: "Bar"
    }
```

Am I missing a return statement, or am I missing something with how `map` returns values after a `.then()`? I'm unclear on why the compile warning would appear at all.

Comment: for nested then previous then "here  .then(res => res.json())  " should return a  promise

Comment: This arrow function in the argument does return a promise. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try Changing `map(() => {}) to map(() => ())`

{} -  Creates a code block that expects an explicit `return` statement.
With () -  implicit return takes place.

Comment: `{} - Creates a code block that expects an explicit return statement.` that hint solved my issue. i added `return` to the final value

Comment: Works, changing the curly braces to brackets did it!

Comment: yes, ı use react and i resolved my problem with this way.

Answer (score 66):

Your specific example is:

```js
data.map(users => {
   console.log(users);
});
```

Where `data` is the following array:

```js
[
  {id: 1, username: "Foo"},
  {id: 2, username: "Bar"},
]
```

---

`data.map` function (check [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) specification) converts one array (`data` in your case) to a new array. The conversion (mapping) is defined by the argument of `data.map`, also called the callback function. In your case, the callback function is the arrow function `users => {console.log(users);}`. **The callback function of `data.map` must return a value.** By returning a value for each item of the array is how `data.map` defines the mapping.

But in your case the callback function does not return anything. Your intention is not to do any kind of mapping, but just to `console.log`. So in your case you can use `data.forEach` ([Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)) as you don't use `data.map` functionality.

NOTE: Also you should have singular (rather than plural) name for the parameter of the callback function: `data.map(user => {console.log(user);});` as this parameter is set to the individual element from the old array.

Comment: Worked for me thx

Answer (score 20):

If you don't need to mutate the array and just do the console.log() you can do data.forEach() instead. It shouldn't give you the warning. Map expects you to return a value after you've transformed the array.

```
fetch('/users')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            data.forEach(users => {
                console.log(users);
            });
        });
```

Comment: It expects you to return a value for an element of the array and that will be called for every element. So maybe "after you transformed the element" would make sense. Also `map()` does not mutate the array. It creates a new one.

Answer (score 9):

From MDN:

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

That means the map method has to be returned. So,you should change your code like this:

```
fetch('/users')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        data.map(users => {
            return console.log(users);
        });
    });
```

or use forEach() instead of map()

Comment: Returning the console log will fix the error but as `console.log()` does return `undefined` you would get an array of undefined values which will be quiet useless. `forEach()` is the best choice in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Should be a implicit return use () in place for {}.

try this

```
fetch('/users')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        data.map(users => (
            console.log(users);
        ));
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method mapping data `map(() => ())` instead of this `map(() => {})`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30658207)

Answer (score 1):

***it's brings this error complain when i destruction like this***

```
{ people.map((person) => (
const [id,name,age,image] = person;
        <return>
            <article className='person' key={id}>
            <img src={image} alt={name} />
            <div>      
        <h4>{name}</h4>        
        <p>{age} Years</p>
            </div>
        </article>
        </return>
  ))}
```

**so i now do it this way without destruction and its work for me**

```
{ people.map((person) => (
        <return>
            <article className='person' key={person.id}>
            <img src={person.image} alt={person.name} />
            <div>      
        <h4>{person.name}</h4>        
        <p>{person.age} Years</p>
            </div>
        </article>
        </return>
  ))}
```